# ApacheShiro -SSO using Storm path

Tags: java, tomcat7, single-sign-on, shiro, stormpath

I have set up my two applications in single tomcat instance using the procedure described in [Can I SSO between multiple Wars in the same servlet with Stormpath and Apache Shiro?](https://support.stormpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/203815036-Can-I-SSO-between-multiple-Wars-in-the-same-servlet-with-Stormpath-and-Apache-Shiro-)

Both of the WARs run fine individually with the users registered in Stormpath directory. But when I link the two applications and do successful login in War A, still redirected to the Login Page of WAR B and I need to login again. I also see the jSessionId is different on login page of WAR A and WAR B. So somehow both the applications are not getting linked.

Answer (score 1):

Shiro has a session mechanism which allows you clustering. See http://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html#SessionManagement-SessionClustering
Shiro has also an extension: buji-pac4j (https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j) which new version (1.4.0) has a support for Stormpath.
So using both will help you achieve SSO with Stormpath.